# SELECT with placeholder in C

Tags: c, select, sqlite

it's my first question here because I'm having this problem for days now;
I'm kinda new to coding so I don't understand some parts of code libraries like sqlite3.

I need to do a SELECT in my database and I don't know how to properly bind a placeholder. I know it should look something like this:

```
int main(void) {

char lastName[50];
char *err_msg = 0;
sqlite3_stmt * pStmt;
int rc = 0;

rc = dbconnect();

if (rc == 1)
{

   printf("Please enter your family name: \t\t");
   scanf("%s", lastName);

   char *sql = "SELECT FirstName FROM Player WHERE LastName = ?";

   rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, lastName, 4, &pStmt, NULL);

   rc = sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 1, "Miller", 3, NULL);
}

rc = dbexecute(sql, callback_firstCol);
return 0;
}
```

There is some more code for the connection and the execution, I don't know if you need to see all.

The problem is the replacement of "?" with the variable lastName and I can't manage to do it.
I googled for days and found out I need a "sqlite3_prepare_v2" and "sqlite3_bind_text" but I don't understand all the arguments I have to pass over (you see me trying in the code). I also read that the "sqlite_exec" needs to be replaced with "sqlite3_step".

Maybe you can't help me in detail, but maybe you have a good documentation of this, the ones I found didn't work for me. Thank you.